# array of same objects

Tags: c#, arrays

If i want to declare an array of same objects(I mean same constructor paramter values). can i do it in one shot.

In the below example If i want to create 4 box objects with same dimensions (3, 3, 2), I called the constructor 4 times. Can i do this in one shot?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Box b = new Box(3, 4, 7);
        Console.WriteLine(b.getVolume());

        Box[] matchBoxes = new Box[4];
        matchBoxes[0] = new Box(3, 3, 2);
        matchBoxes[1] = new Box(3, 3, 2);
        matchBoxes[2] = new Box(3, 3, 2);
        matchBoxes[3] = new Box(3, 3, 2);


        Console.ReadLine();

    }


}

class Box
{
    private int length;
    private int breadth;
    private int height;
    public Box(int l, int b, int h)
    {
        this.length = l;
        this.breadth = b;
        this.height = h;
    }
    public int getVolume()
    {
        return (this.length*this.breadth*this.height);
    }

}
```

Comment: Also, I cannot really see why you would need this in one shot. This is very clear for me and it isn't too complex. It would be more complex to do it in one shot

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=breadth&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: @JohnSaunders Lol, I really had no idea. Weird word

Comment: It means, "the characteristic of being broad"

Comment: @JohnSaunders It's also a synonym to "Width". Never heard it been used tho

Answer (score 3):

That depends. Since this is a `class` you would need to call `new` 4 times **if** you want to get 4 different objects. However, your box looks to be immutable; if you are happy to use the same object 4 times (which might be reasonable here), you could use:

```
var box = new Box(3,3,2);
var matchBoxes = new[] {box,box,box,box};
```

If that is the entirety of your `Box` type, you *might* also want to consider making it a `struct` (immutable, small, value-esque - definite`struct` candidate). Then it is moot : it **will** be a different *value* in each position. The construction could be the same as above, though.

Comment: Your array will contain 4 identical objects - i.e. one object 4 times. I think this is not what Preveen wants.

Comment: @Karel please read what I wrote; I noted that the type is immutable, so it might be reasonable to use the same instance 4 times. I also emphasised that *if* you want a different instance each time, you need to call `new` each time.

Comment: I understand you, but Praveen asked the question and he was not talking about "immutability".

Comment: @KarelFrajtak Does it really matter what he was talking about? As long as it's applicable (which it is), I would say it's fine

Comment: @Karel I provided *options*. In the question asked, with the sample shown, it is *entirely* reasonable to re-use the instance, which I have illustrated. Regardless of the OP mentioning immutability, that still applies here and it is right to note it. I *also* mention that if you **want** different objects, you'd need to use `new` each time. Please: what *specifically* are you criticizing? It is often important to look beyond simply what the OP is asking in words, but to look at the context to understand the full scenario. I feel I have done so.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry - I skimmed your answer, please edit it, so I can undo my downvote.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create 4 new objects, you have to call constructor 4 times. If you do not want to type it, use cycle:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) matchBoxes[i] = new Box(3, 3, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Many of the answers are spot on (use a struct, use a loop);

Just to be complete:

```
    Box[] matchBoxes = Enumerable.Repeat(new Box(3, 3, 2), 4).ToArray();
```

**Note** as Marc Gravell stated that this will *NOT* give separate copies of the Box, unless it is a valuetype.

You could even make it more general:

```
    var generator   = Enumerable.Repeat(new Box(3, 3, 2));

    // ....
    var fourBoxes   = generator.Take(4);
    var twentyBoxes = generator.Take(20);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var matchBoxes = Enumerable.Repeat(new Box(3, 3, 2), 4).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope. each object needs to be created separately.
Use a loop :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a loop, with parameters to be passed in constructors?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solve your problem,

```
Box[] matchBoxes = new Box[]{ new Box(3, 3, 2), new Box(3, 3, 2), new Box(3, 3, 2), new Box(3, 3, 2)};
```

Comment: Mmmm. _Some_ might say it became worse. It _did_ remove the redundant specification of the array length, I guess